# sandbox issue in Yosemite (OSX 10.10)

Tags: macos, perl, cocoa, cups, osx-yosemite

I have a virtual printer with the CUPS backend which is perl script to write a postscript file to /Applications/User folder. It is working in 10.7 to 10.9. Now I am testing this on Yosemite dev preview 5 and it is failing to create the file to the folder. It is showing sandbox error in 10.10.

"sandoxd: perl5.18 deny file-read-metadata"

How do we take care of this issue? Is there any generic folder which can be used to write file to? How can we resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had nearly the exact same problem. I solved it by moving the dependencies from /opt/msipp to /usr/share/cups/msipp.

Comment: /Users/Shared/<Custom folder> is one of the recommended folder to write postscript. After the change everything works fine.